# Why does binary accuracy give high accuracy while categorical accuracy give low accuracy, in a multi-class classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, classification, multiclass-classification

I'm working on a multiclass classification problem using Keras and I'm using binary accuracy and categorical accuracy as metrics. When I evaluate my model I get a really high value for the binary accuracy and quite a low one in for the categorical accuracy. I tried to recreate the binary accuracy metric in my own code but I am not having much luck. My understanding is that this is the process I need to recreate:

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
     return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

Here is my code:

```
from keras import backend as K
preds = model.predict(X_test, batch_size = 128)

print preds
pos = 0.00
neg = 0.00

for i, val in enumerate(roundpreds):

    if val.tolist() == y_test[i]:
        pos += 1.0

    else: 
        neg += 1.0

print pos/(pos + neg)
```

But this gives a much lower value than the one given by binary accuracy. Is binary accuracy even an appropriate metric to be using in a multi-class problem? If so does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use binary accuracy for a multiclass problem, the results would not make sense.

Answer (score 21):

So you need to understand what happens when you apply a `binary_crossentropy` to a multiclass prediction.

1. Let's assume that your output from `softmax` is `(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)` and one-hot encoded ground truth is `(1, 0, 0, 0)`.
2. `binary_crossentropy` masks all outputs which are higher than `0.5` so out of your network is turned to `(0, 0, 0, 0)` vector.
3. `(0, 0, 0, 0)` matches ground truth `(1, 0, 0, 0)` on 3 out of 4 indexes - this makes resulting accuracy to be at the level of **75%** for a **completely wrong answer**!

To solve this you could use a single class accuracy, e.g. like this one:

```
def single_class_accuracy(interesting_class_id):
    def fn(y_true, y_pred):
        class_id_preds = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        # Replace class_id_preds with class_id_true for recall here
        positive_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_preds, interesting_class_id), 'int32')
        true_mask = K.cast(K.equal(y_true, interesting_class_id), 'int32')
        acc_mask = K.cast(K.equal(positive_mask, true_mask), 'float32')
        class_acc = K.mean(acc_mask)
        return class_acc

    return fn
```